# How do I expose ASP.NET Core Identify to Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-identity

I have setup a asp.net core Web API 2 project with authorisation and when I migrated my Entity Framework code first it created the `AspNetUsers`. I have now added my swagger doc to the site but their is no methods to register a user etc how do I register the asp.net Identity methods to register a user verify a user etc to the swagger site.

Do I need to create my own `AccountController`? Or is there a way to expose those methods to swagger?

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "App Manager - Running Buddies", Version = "v1" });

//Expose XML comments in doc.
c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Description =
                "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
         {
             new OpenApiSecurityScheme
             {
               Reference = new OpenApiReference
              {
               Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
              },
              Scheme = "oauth2",
              Name = "Bearer",
              In = ParameterLocation.Header
           },
           new List<string>()
         }
       });

 });
```

[image]